# Why is my function runs twice in OnTriggerStay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a simple game in **Unity**.

The situation is like if I kill an enemy, it drops a pickupable Health. 
In the **OnTriggerEnter**, I handle the player collision with the health, and if the player misses health, it heals a certain amount. (70 exactly)

When player is standing on the health while at maximum health, it does nothing. But if player got damaged while standing on the health, the health should also be picked up, that is where **OnTriggerStay** comes in.

There I constantly check if the player needs heeling, if do, do the healing, and destroy the heal object.
My problem is that it runs twice. It heals the amount twice to the player. No matter what I do, the function I call in **OnTriggerStay** is gonna run twice. Why is that? Anybody knows the solution?

Here is the part of my Player.cs file, and my Heal.cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
  //HP and MANA system
    [SerializeField]
    private int playerHealth;
    [SerializeField]
    private int playerMaxHealth = 100;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform Healthbar;

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > attackSpeed)
            {
                Enemy enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
                if (enemy != null)
                {
                    enemy.DamageEnemy(playerDamage);
                }
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
        }
        if (other.tag == "PatrollingEnemy")
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > attackSpeed)
            {
                PatrollingEnemy enemy = other.GetComponent<PatrollingEnemy>();
                if (enemy != null)
                {
                    enemy.DamageEnemy(playerDamage);
                }
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
        }
        if (other.tag == "Heal")
        {
            heal(other, false);

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Heal")
        {
            heal(other, false);
        }
        else if (other.tag == "HealthPotion")
        {
            heal(other, true);
        }
    }
    private void heal(Collider other, bool isPotion)
    {

        dynamic heal;
        if (isPotion)
        {
            heal = other.GetComponent<HealthPotion>();
        }
        else
        {
            heal = other.GetComponent<Heal>();
        }
        if (playerHealth < playerMaxHealth && heal != null)
        {
            addHealthToPlayer(heal.HealAmount);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void addHealthToPlayer(int amount)
    {

        playerHealth += amount;
        if (playerHealth > playerMaxHealth)
        {
            playerHealth = playerMaxHealth;
        }
        rescaleHealthBar();
    }

    private void rescaleHealthBar()
    {
        Healthbar.transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)playerHealth / (float)playerMaxHealth, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    } 
}


public class Heal : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 0.0f;
    float destroyTimer = 0.0f;
    float timeWhenDestroy = 15f;
    Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(0, 45, 0);

    private int healAmount = 70;
    public int HealAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return healAmount;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        destroyTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (destroyTimer > timeWhenDestroy)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        transform.Rotate(rotation * Time.deltaTime);
        if (timer < 1.0f)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (timer > 1.0f)
        {
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (timer > 2.0f)
        {
            timer = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OnTriggerStay is working over multiple frames, add a bool that change when collected eg: `if(!collected){collected = true;}` do a flag check like that will stop it

Comment: But If the player picks up the health, the heal object get destroyed. How is it still doing the heal, when the object does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Maybe both your events (Enter & Stay) are fired during that frame ?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html

> OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for every Collider other that is touching the trigger. The function is on the physics timer so it won't necessarily run every frame.